# Node.js Express3 to Express4 migration - parser usage

Tags: json, node.js, express, multer, body-parser

My Node based server uses Express. The server handles json only routes and file upload routes which use multi-part forms. When using Express3, the built in parser was parsing both kinds of routes. I am in the process of migrating to Express4. The body-parser, that I had to switch for Express4, only parses jsons. I am using multer parser to parse file uploads.

For each route, I am specifying which parser to use, as in:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var multer = require('multer');

var jsonParser = bodyParser.json();
var upload = multer({dest : 'upload/' });
var uploadParser = upload.any();
var app = express();

// json route handling
app.post('json_only_route', jsonParser, function(req, res) {...});

// upload route handling
app.post('upload_route',    uploadParser, function(req, res) {...});
```

Alternatively, for json only parsing, I could use the multer parser as well, as below:

```
var jsonParserMulter = uploadParser.none();

// json route handling
app.post('json_only_route', jsonParserMulter, function(req, res) {...});
```

Are there any reasons to use one approach over the other? Would 'body-parser' offer better performance for json only parsing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like multer doesn't support JSON. By using `uploadParser.none()` it will just pass through the JSON as a string. Express' `bodyParser.json()` is the way to go if you want to parse the JSON string into an object.